# OnKillFocus is getting Called Twice

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I have one Dialog box where it's consist 3 EditControl boxes and 2 for Validating the Enter Data. When the Editcontrol is lost focus we are validating the entered data using OnKillFocus method and facing the Hang issue because of calling OnKIllFocus multiple times, after that we separated each KillFocus for each Editcontrol still also we are facing the same issue calling KillFocus multiple times

```
`BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CWHPwdDlg, CDialog)
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDOK, OnOK)
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDCANCEL, OnCancel)
    ON_WM_CTLCOLOR()
    ON_EN_KILLFOCUS(IDC_HMI_SERVERNAME, OnKillFocusServerNameTextBox)
    ON_EN_KILLFOCUS(IDC_WH_RT_PORT, OnKillFocusPortTextBox)
    ON_EN_KILLFOCUS(IDC_HMI_USERNAME, OnKillFocusUserNameTextBox)
    ON_EN_KILLFOCUS(IDC_HMI_PASSWORD, OnKillFocusPwdTextBox)
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_WH_RT_TEST_CONNECTION, OnTestConnection)
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_WH_RT_VIEW_CERT, OnViewCertificate)
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_WH_RT_REQUIRE_TRUST, OnCheckEnableTrust)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()


void CWHPwdDlg::OnKillFocusServerNameTextBox()
{
    MessageBoxA(NULL, "Click", "Servername", MB_OK);
    if (!UpdateData(TRUE)) {
        return;
    }

    CWnd* pWndOk = GetDlgItem(IDOK);

    //if (m_hmiServerName.IsEmpty())
    if(m_hmiServerName.GetLength()<=0)
    {
        m_TestConnection.EnableWindow(FALSE);

        SetDlgItemText(IDC_WH_RT_TRUSTED_MSG, _T(""));
        CWnd* p_CertificateButton = GetDlgItem(IDC_WH_RT_VIEW_CERT);
        if (p_CertificateButton != NULL)
            p_CertificateButton->EnableWindow(FALSE);
        CWnd* pTrustCheck = GetDlgItem(IDC_WH_RT_REQUIRE_TRUST);
        if (pTrustCheck != NULL)
            pTrustCheck->EnableWindow(FALSE);

        m_whErrorStr.SetWindowText(m_strServerNameError);
        m_whErrorStr.ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
        m_whErrorIcon.ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
        pWndOk->EnableWindow(FALSE);

        return;
    }
    else
    {

        SetCertificateAndEnableViewer();
    }
}


void CWHPwdDlg::OnKillFocusPortTextBox()
{
    MessageBoxA(NULL, "Click", "KillPort", MB_OK);

    if (!UpdateData(TRUE)) {
        return;
    }


    CWnd* pWndOk = GetDlgItem(IDOK);

    if (m_hmiPortNum.IsEmpty() || m_hmiPortNum == _T("0"))
    {
        m_whErrorStr.SetWindowText(m_strPortError);
        m_whErrorStr.ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
        m_whErrorIcon.ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
        pWndOk->EnableWindow(FALSE);
        //return FALSE;
    }

}

void CWHPwdDlg::OnKillFocusUserNameTextBox()
{
    MessageBoxA(NULL, "Click", "KillUserName", MB_OK);
    if (!UpdateData(TRUE)) {
        return;
    }


    CWnd* pWndOk = GetDlgItem(IDOK);

    if (m_hmiUserName.IsEmpty())
    {
        m_whErrorStr.SetWindowText(m_strUserNameError);
        m_whErrorStr.ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
        m_whErrorIcon.ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
        pWndOk->EnableWindow(FALSE);
        //  return FALSE;
    }

}
```

`

Comment: If you are going to use the DDX/DDV feature, you may not call `UpdateData(TRUE)` yourself in OnKillFocus. `DoDataExchange()` performs checks (among others) and you can put additional validation code in there (after the wizard-generated code). Typically this takes place in `OnOK()`. Also, don't display message-boxes and set focus to another control in OnKillFocus. It may indeed cause additional kill-focus messages to be sent.

Comment: [WM_KILLFOCUS is the wrong time to do field validation](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040419-00/?p=39753). Any reason you aren't using MFC's built-in validation implementation? See [Dialog Data Validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/dialog-data-validation).

Comment: There are good reasons to do own validation before/instead of MFCs DDV, for instance to provide early, unobtrusive feedback about invalid input. For edit controls, this is usually done in `ON_EN_CHANGE` handler though. A dialog box as shown by MFCs DDV is **not** considered unobtrusive feedback. Less obtrusive ways include drawing a red frame around the control and/or [showing a tooltip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cedit-class?view=vs-2019#showballoontip).